# Looping over array with nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, for-loop

I am trying to loop over an array of nested object to seed my mongodb. I was able to achieve using the following for loop, but the issue with this one is that it picks a random object from the array.

```
const seedDB =  async() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        const which = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
        const seedLeague =  new League({
            title : `${leagues[which].title}`,
            location : `${leagues[which].location}`,
            city: `${leagues[which].city}`, 
            lat: `${leagues[which].lat}`,
            lon: `${leagues[which].lon}`
        })
        await seedLeague.save();
    }
 }
```

What I actually want is to loop of the array and add each object in the array. I tried to achieve that using a forEach and for (element of array), but both are giving a typeError.

```
const seedDB =  async() => {
    await League.deleteMany({});
    leagues.forEach( async (i)=>{
        new League({
            title : `${leagues[i].title}`,
            location : `${leagues[i].location}`,
            city: `${leagues[i].city}`, 
            lat: `${leagues[i].lat}`,
            lon: `${leagues[i].lon}`
        })
        await League.save();
    })
}

const seedDB =  async() => {
    await League.deleteMany({});
    for (let aLeague of leagues) {
        new League({
            title : `${leagues[aLeague].title}`,
            location : `${leagues[aLeague].location}`,
            city: `${leagues[aLeague].city}`, 
            lat: `${leagues[aLeague].lat}`,
            lon: `${leagues[aLeague].lon}`
        })
        await League.save();
    }
```

Could someone please help and fix the issue with above forEach and for .. of ..?

Comment: post an input example (even though probably `leagues.forEach(l => {...})` might be enough)

Comment: Is leagues an array or object?

Answer (score 0):

In the second two you are calling .save() on the League class instead of on an instance of that class. In the first one you are assigning each new instance to a const (seedLeague) and calling save on that.

The second two options should both work, you just need to create a const inside each iteration of the loop and call save on that new object:

```
const seedDB =  async() => {
   await League.deleteMany({});
   leagues.forEach( async (i)=>{
       const seedLeague = new League({
           title : `${leagues[i].title}`,
           location : `${leagues[i].location}`,
           city: `${leagues[i].city}`, 
           lat: `${leagues[i].lat}`,
           lon: `${leagues[i].lon}`
       })
       await seedLeague.save();
   })
}
```